# Column by column pairplotting of 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to be able to plot two dataframes against each other pairing each column successively (but not all columns against all columns). The dataframes are identical in size and column headers but differ in the values. So the dataframes are of the form:

```
df_X =
    A   B   C
0   1   1   1
1   2   2   2
...

df_Y =
    A   B   C
0   3   3   3
1   4   4   4
...
```

At the moment I can do this manually on subplots using by starting with a merged dataframe with two header columns:

```
df_merge =
col A       B       C   
    X   Y   X   Y   X   Y
0   1   3   1   3   1   3
1   2   4   2   4   2   4
...

_, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1)
for i in range(3):
    ax[i].scatter(df_merge[col[i]][X], df_merge[col[i]][Y])
```

This works, but I am wondering if there is a better way of acheving this. Particularly when trying to then calculate the numerical correlation value between the pairs, which would again involve another loop and several more lines of code.

Comment: what are `col`, `X`, `Y`?

Comment: col is just the columns A, B and C. X and Y are the two original dataframes, each one has a data series for each of A, B and C. So the combined is a multi-index column headers, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can get correlation with something like:

```
df_merge[[col[i]][X],col[i]][Y]]).corr()
```

You can generally assume that most statistical functions can be applied in a single line to dataframe content either with built-in Pandas functions (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/computation.html), or scipy/numpy functions which you can apply.

To title each plot with the correlation, for example, you can do

```
thisAX.set_title("Corr: {}".format(df_merge[[col[i]][X],col[i]][Y]]).corr())
```

[image]

(I flattened your column names to make display a bit simpler, and I reversed one of the number pairs to show negative correlation)

Note: when feeding two Pandas columns (Series) into .corr(), you'll get a dataframe returned - to get the X:Y correlation, you can pick out a single value with `.corr()["{}_X".format(col[i])]["{}_Y".format(col[i])]))`   (those are just the column and index names of the correlation)

Here's a lightly styled version of the same plot (again, using the flattened version of your column names)

[image]